# How prove $\frac{a^2}{(a+b)^2}+\frac{b^2}{(b+c)^2}+\frac{c^2}{(c+a)^2} \ge \frac{3}{4}+\frac{(a-b)(b-c)(a-c)}{(a+b+c)^3-3abc} $?

Tags: inequality

Let $a \ge b \ge c >0$ . How can I prove

$$\frac{a^2}{(a+b)^2}+\frac{b^2}{(b+c)^2}+\frac{c^2}{(c+a)^2} \ge \frac{3}{4}+\frac{(a-b)(b-c)(a-c)}{(a+b+c)^3-3abc}. $$
Maybe a simple way?

Comment: is it realy $(a-b)(b-c)(a-c)$ or $(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)$?

Comment: you can use BW to prove this

Comment: If I did no stupid error then my Mathcad computational  evidence suggests that even more strong inequality holds:

$$LHS \ge \frac 13\left(\frac{a}{a+b}+\frac{b}{b+c}+\frac{c}{c+a}\right)^2\ge RHS.$$

Answer (score 0):

I think a simplest way here is a full expanding:
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}(5a^7b^2+a^7c^2+13a^6b^3+9a^6c^3+18a^5b^4+18a^5c^4+2a^7bc+15a^6b^2c+11a^6c^2b+$$
$$+11a^5b^3c+15a^5c^3b+16a^4b^4c-6a^5b^2c^2-50a^4b^3c^2-50a^4c^3b^2-28a^2b^2c^2)\geq0,$$
which is obviously true.

Comment: May I ask how you know that this (or the other > 10 questions where you added the [contest-math] tag recently) is a *"Problem from or inspired by mathematics competitions"* in the sense of http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/contest-math/info?

Comment: @Martin R 2 Because I participated and I am teaching to contests and I just know how seems an olimpiad's problem.

Comment: I am not sure if the [contest-math] tag should be added to all questions with "seem to look like" an Olympiads question with further justification, therefore I asked on meta: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/25535/42969, but without any feedback so far. You are invited to post your opinion on that matter!